# An image background is not visible when cells filled with background-color is that part using xslt

Tags: xslt, background-image

Good day, I'm using apache-fop and in my xslt code I added an image as background (watermark) but in some parts there are cells of a table that are filled with color using background-color attribute and the image-background is not visible in those parts. I was looking for information to chnage that cells transparent with the color they have but I haven't found nothing useful.

I tried to set my background image with fo:external-graphic but it doesnt fit in all the document as a watermark, I need help to show the entire image in all my documents with the cells coloured.

I'm using this to put the background image:

```xml
<fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:simple-page-master page-height="216mm" page-width="279mm" margin="8.5mm" master-name="FacturaPlantilla">
    <fo:region-body margin-bottom="10mm" margin-top="62mm" background-image="C:\ITC\FC4\RepresentacionGrafica\CFDI\Cancelado_Nomina.jpg" background-position="center"  background-repeat="no-repeat"/>
    <fo:region-before extent="92mm" />
    <fo:region-after extent="7mm" />
  </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
```

This is the problem:

[image]

Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Apache FOP has limited capabilities. So there is no way to make watermark visible with FOP in this case.